# Specifying directly factor levels and sizes

Tags: r, r-factor

How would you create a factor with levels and corresponding sizes directly specified?

```
e.g. [0, 5) 6
     [5, 7) 20
     [7, 13) 4
```

Edit: This question is related to grouped frequency distributions. Sometimes (say in textbooks), you don't get access to original data but you're just given the count of the occurrences of values within each class. Later on, you'd want to compute cumulative count/frequency, you'd like to tell what count such or such class has and so on. So you just need to be able to enter the class table and hence my question.

Second edit:
Typical textbook example (it's already a summary, the original data set is not available):

```
[20, 30) 221890
[30, 35) 171050
[35, 40) 121400
[40, 45) 101050
[45, 60)  71620
# ... possibly many more but let's stop here.
```

Then typical questions are: what is the tally for the [30, 35) class? What is the cumlative count at 45? Plot the corresponding histogram, and so on and so forth.

So @thelatemail 1st comment provided a workable answer but I was worried about the resulting factor 'size'. That's why I asked for other alternative solutions. @agstudy answer also works along the same lines but with the extra burden of recreating a (temporary, agreed) whole new data set. Still it's an interesting answer by itself. I was in particular interested in the way @agstudy computed the temporary data set.

All in all, these solutions work but I would like some optimized approach if at all possible.

Theoretically, 'factor's would be the needed output but 'factor's seem way too big to store that summary table.

Answer (score 3):

For example using `cut` you can do this:

```
cut(rep(c(1,6,11),c(6,20,4)),c(0,5,7,13))
```

You can check using `table`

```
table(cut(rep(c(1,6,11),c(6,20,4)),c(0,5,7,13)))
 (0,5]  (5,7] (7,13] 
     6     20      4
```

**EDIT** to create data from intervals you can do this also :

```
cut(rep((c(0,5,7,13) +1)[-1],c(6,20,4)),c(0,5,7,13))
```

**EDIT** even after clarification is still not clear for me what do you have as inputs specially the structure of your inputs data. Here a straight method:

```
text='[20, 30) 221890
[30, 35) 171050
[35, 40) 121400
[40, 45) 101050
[45, 60)  71620'

dd <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(readLines(textConnection(text)),') '))

vv <- as.numeric(dd[,2])
names(vv) <- paste0(dd[,1],')')

vv
[20, 30) [30, 35) [35, 40) [40, 45) [45, 60) 
  221890   171050   121400   101050    71620
```

Comment: No. It's not exactly what is wanted as your approach doesn't scale well. You need to recreate fake data here before building the mock factor. Edit: to be clear, computing the 1, 6, 11 is cumbersome ..

Comment: Maybe it's better to compute the mid-ranges .. still, we need to go the extra path of recreating fake data. I really don't like it as the desired output is somehow a summary of some data already.

Comment: @greendiod Try to clarify your question! I think it will be closed.

Comment: @agstudu Have you read the edit in my original question? When I talked about fake date, take no offense, I just meant that seemed to me an extra step that could be avoided as the contingency table is already a summary of the original data.

Comment: @greendiod don't worry. It is really fake data so no offense. You should clarify your question : For example , you should say I have such inputs ( you create a sample of your data)  and I would get such output ( vector , or table ..). Once you do it I will vote to reopen it.

Comment: I finished editing the original question. The point I want to make clear is there is no original set. And that's the whole point of the question. We start with a data summary, the class tally table.

Comment: given your vv object, how would you answer the typical textbook questions I provided in the clarification? (say what is the tally for the [30, 35) class? What is the cumlative count at 45? ...)